# Can't find where content type is in use

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, pnp

Using CSOM, I created a list, a content type and then I added the content type to the list.
Then using PnP PowerShell I wanted to delete both the list and the content type so I wrote:

```
Remove-PnPList -Identity "Flash Reports" -Force
Remove-PnPContentType -Identity "Flash report" -Force
```

The list is correctly removed but the second line throws an error saying that "The content type is in use".
When I go the SharePoint site, I can see that the list was correctly removed but the content type always appears in site content types.

I used different scripts / tools (e.g. SharePoint Manager) to check where the content could be used but I found nothing...
Do you know what could be the issue ?
Thanks,

Comment: Typically you have to delete the list from the recycle bin before you can delete the content type

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to say that I emptied the recycle bin, the admin recycle bin as well. Doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the problem. 
Since the same content type with the same GUID is used on multiple webs of the same site collection I cannot delete it as long as the content type is in use on any of the SharePoint site.